# How to generate video preview thumbnails using nodejs and ffmpeg?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, html5-video, video-processing

I am creating a custom video player,  I would like to add a video preview when the user hovers a progress bar.

I am able to generate thumbnails using FFmpeg as follows.

```sh
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex \
    "select='not(mod(n,60))',scale=240:-1,tile=layout=4x8" \
    -vframes 1 -q:v 2 outputfile.jpg
```

**PROBLEM**

To use the above-created sprite image(combined thumbnails), I need to generate a `WEBVTT` which contains thumbnails and frames time interval like this below.

```text
WEBVTT

00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:03.000
thumbnails.jpg#xywh=0,0,120,68

00:00:03.000 --> 00:00:06.000
thumbnails.jpg#xywh=120,0,120,68

00:00:06.000 --> 00:00:09.000
thumbnails.jpg#xywh=240,0,120,68
```

I am not able to find any FFmpeg command or tutorial on how to create such WEBVTT file using node-js and FFmpeg.

Maybe someone here knows the solution to this problem? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you change the error output, you can see that the problem is with permissions.  `console.error("Async: Could not copy text: ", err.message);`   Full text of error: Async: Could not copy text: The Clipboard API has been blocked because of a permissions policy applied to the current document. See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-permissions-in-cross-origin-iframes for more details.

Comment: Any particular reason why you [edited an existing question into something completely unrelated](/revisions/69846515/3) instead of opening a new question?

Comment: Are you looking for a tool or code sample? It is doesn't look extremely difficult to solve using a Python script... (are you looking for JavaScript implementation?)

Comment: @Rotem I need Javascript implementation

Comment: @TheDeadMan for Javascript version, you simply need to create your VTT as a String via a For loop. You'll need vars for holding the expected x, y, w and h values (as they change for each VTT line). **PS:** Are you using JWPlayer / VideoJS for your custom player? I see it's those player that need VTT for thumbnails. If not restricted to VTT, you could just have a canvas floating above your seekbar where its image is a tile from the larger main image (updated by the seeking position). Are you interested in that idea or it really needs to be VTT?

Comment: @VC.One I am creating a custom video player,  it can be canvas but I tried canvas by creating an image after every 5 seconds and appending this div to seek bar preview container it works but only video from the same domain/origin if using a link from another domain u will get the following error: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported. that is why I decided to use ffmpeg and nodejs to create sprite image then create vtt using this image

Comment: @VC.One I think webVTT method is better and has no cors problem, all video players out there Netflix, youtube, JW Player, amazon player  etc use VTT to display thumbnails

Comment: @TheDeadMan **(1)** Actually I was thinking of Youtube when I suggested Canvas for showing each tile, then you got me all excited with _"Youtube uses VTT"_,  but after checking the Network tab in Dev Tools, it's still not using VTT for anything after all these years. **(2)** I hear you on the CORS issue but you already have the image `outputfile.jpg` from FFmpeg, I'm saying skip the VTT file part and just load the image when you load the video. Once in memory every needed tile will be instant access. I can show it if useful, I just didn't want to write that code if you were locked to VTT only.

Comment: @VC.One okay you can provide your solution it might be a good solution

Comment: @TheDeadMan I haven't forgotten you. I am busy with a tough (but cool) project. I'll try post before 8pm (its 2pm for me now). Also can you confirm if you are involving JWPlayer/VideoJS for the WebVTT. I'm asking because I am thinking it might be possible to not save a file but instead just send it **directly** to a JW player instance (after dynamically creating VTT with a function). I also have an idea that avoids CORS (thumbnails don't have to be in same server). Check later.

Comment: @VC.One I am creating my own video player inspired by JWPlayer and youtube player, I am ble to generate thumbnails and VTT files now I am working on combining this together when user provides a video link to player 1. generate the thumbnails using FFmpeg 2. generate VTT file using ur script and generate thumbnails via backend nodejs and then display the thumbanilasd to browser , u can provide me email  I will give update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to make your own tool for creating the WEBVTT file.
And it's a simple process, you just need to get the information you need and fill it in the following format:

```
00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:03.000
thumbnails.jpg#xywh=0,0,120,68
```

and then save the file.

***Example:***

Let's say you have a video that's 60 seconds long.
You use **ffmpeg** to generate 10 thumbnails.

You write a short program (in this case Node.js) that loops based on the number of thumbnails following the above format a manner similar to this:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const moment = require('moment')

let video_length = 60
let number_of_thumbnails = 10
let thumb_interval = video_length/number_of_thumbnails // so 6 seconds per thumbnail

let sprite_width = 600 // Values are assumed based each thumbnail having
let sprite_height = 340 //a width of 120 and a height of 68 with a total of 10

let start_time = moment('00:00:00', "HH:mm:ss.SSS")
let end_time = moment('00:00:00', "HH:mm:ss.SSS").add(thumb_interval , 'seconds')

let thumb_output = "WEBVTT\n\n"

for(let i=0;i<=(sprite_height /68);i++){
  for(let j=0;j<=(sprite_width/120);j++){

    thumb_output +=start_time.format("HH:mm:ss.SSS") +" --> "+ end_time.format("HH:mm:ss.SSS")+"\n"

    thumb_output += "thumbnails.jpg#xywh="+(j*120)+","+(i*68)+",120,68\n\n"

    start_time.add(thumb_interval , 'seconds')
    end_time.add(thumb_interval , 'seconds')
  }
}

fs.writeFileSync('thumbnails.vtt', thumb_output)
```

The library *Moment.js* was used for simplifying the time incrementation & format

Comment: Instead of i=< and j=< it should be i<= and j<=

Comment: @ManuelMB ahh yes thank you for pointing it out

Comment: @gNazi I tested with thumbnails generated using a video with 10 minutes when I generate the thumbnails I see a video end time equal to `00:20: 17.018` but the video just has 10 minutes, what do I need to change here so that the thumbnails generated end time should be equal to the end time of the video : check screen shots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHkha.png